# After upgrade to latest dropbox, it stopped syncing

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, sync, dropbox

I run ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Few days ago Dropbox started notifying that I have old version installed and that I should upgrade.

I did that, first uninstalled old one, than installed latest dropbox by adding dropbox.com
repository: http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main

It went well, and newest version is installed.

Now I still get nottifications that I run old version!

Bigger problem is: dropbox icon shows that it is trying to sync things all the time, and changes that I made on my machine are not synced to cloud at all!